# undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PCLPointCloud2 const> const&)

Tags: reference, undefined, voxel, pcl

I'm trying to use the VoxelGrid of the pcl library to filter my PointCloud, extracted from a ros message. So the following is the part of code related to this problem:

```
  pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr cloudPtr(cloud_pc2);
  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
  sor.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);
  sor.setLeafSize(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
  sor.filter(cloud_filtered);
```

I saw online tutorials where they directly do:

```
pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
sor.filter (*cloud_filtered);
```

But in both cases I got undefined reference for the setInputCloud function. Have someone an idea of why this happens? I will attach also my CmakeList file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(loam_os2)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  #set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL 1.10 REQUIRED)
find_package(pcl_conversions REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(pcl_example_node src/pcl_example.cpp src/pcl_example_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries( pcl_example_node
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
)

ament_target_dependencies(
  pcl_example_node
  rclcpp 
  std_msgs 
  sensor_msgs 
  pcl_conversions
  tf2
  tf2_ros
  )

install(TARGETS
  pcl_example_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install launch files.
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion

here the full error:

```
usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/pcl_example_node.dir/src/pcl_example.cpp.o: in function Pcl_example::lidar_callback(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >)':
pcl_example.cpp:(.text+0x122f): undefined reference topcl::PCLBase<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PCLPointCloud2 const> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: * [CMakeFiles/pcl_example_node.dir/build.make:360: pcl_example_node] Error 1
make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/pcl_example_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Failed   <<< loam_os2 [12.2s, exited with code 2]
Summary: 0 packages finished [12.5s]
  1 package failed: loam_os2
  1 package had stderr output: loam_os2
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.11.0, PCL uses `std::shared_ptr` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`. It seems you are using PCL 1.10, so `setInputCloud` would expect a `boost::shared_ptr`, however you are passing a `std::shared_ptr`. Since I can't see where `cloudPtr` or `cloud` respectively come from in your code snippets, I am unable to suggest a solution, except to use a newer PCL version.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but even with pcl 1.13 doesn't work, same error. I receive the cloud from a row message so I use the conversion function from pcl library pal_conversion::toPCL(ros PointCloud2 shared pointer to the scan message, pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr)

Comment: Have you removed all PCL installations except PCL 1.13 (to be sure that this one is used), and then built perception_pcl/pcl_conversions from source (also removing the other one installed via apt)?

Comment: yes, pal 1.13 is the only available on the pc and I checked printing from the CMakelist to see if it was actually finding it and it does